# Exporting R data frame to CSV - How can I quote all columns including numeric ones?

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I need to write a CSV with all columns quoted but

```
write.table(param, file=outputFile, row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE, sep=",", dec=".", quote=TRUE)
```

Write this:

```
"maxit","size","decay","resulado","filename"
"1",10000,6,5e-05,0,996363636363636,"result-1.csv"
```

Also dec="." still writing comma for decimals.

What I need:

```
"maxit","size","decay","resulado","filename"
"1","10000","6","5e-05","0.996363636363636","result-1.csv"
```

Some tip?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post as an answer? So I can accept and make easy to others find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From ?write.table:

> Only columns which have been converted to character will be quoted if
>   specified by ‘quote’.

So you can convert to character beforehand and then write to a file. Also, since you want to write a CSV, instead of using `write.table` and mess with every argument separately, you can just use `write.csv` which uses `dec="."` and `sep=","` by default. e.g. if your data frame is DF:

```
DF[] <- lapply(DF, as.character)
write.csv(DF, "foo.csv")
```

Comment: Elegant!! Thanks for `lapply`: http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/

Comment: @MagnoC a really good read for understanding lapply/sapply/vapply is in Hadley's Advanced R online book: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#lapply.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately I can't remove the link from my comment above. 5 minutes for editing is too few. Your document is far better.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `write.table()` function on the result of a call to `format()`:

```
write.table(format(df))
```

This converts all columns to character vectors and also gives you control over how the formatting is done.

```
> sapply(format(mtcars), mode)
        mpg         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt        qsec          vs          am        gear        carb 
"character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character"
```

Comment: This is really handy. A nice example would be `write.csv(format(mtcars))`